# Javascript function won't run twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Jvascript function that when an image is clicked a php file is run and the image that was clicked updates. I made the another function that changes the image back if pressed again. But after running the first function, if you click the image again, nothing is happening. These are my functions:

```
<script>
    function upvote(id,bruger_id)
    {
        $.get("scripts/upvote.php?id="+id+"&bruger_id="+bruger_id, function() {
            // Update image
            $('.changeUp').attr('src', 'images/up.png');
            return;
        });
    }

    function noUpvote(id,bruger_id)
    {
        $.get("scripts/removevote.php?id="+id+"&bruger_id="+bruger_id, function() {
            // Update image
            $('.removeUp').attr('src', 'images/neutral_up.png');
            return;
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is where I call the functions. The base image shown is based on cookies.

```
<img class="changeUp" 
    onclick="upvote('.$feed[$loaded]["id"].','.$feed[$loaded]["bruger_id"].');" 
    src="images/neutral_up.png" width="20px">
```

I realized the error is that it simply calls the same function again and so the image doesn't change back. But how can I work around this then?

Comment: how do you call these functions?

Comment: Can you show us where you assign the click handlers?

Comment: Is the selector matching your image `.changeUp` or `.removeUp`? Both are used in your code.

Comment: added the script that calls the functions

Comment: One simple thing, are you sure that your cookie values are correct when you retrieve them?

Comment: Please don't post your PHP, post the generated HTML version!

Comment: If it is calling the same function then the PHP you posted previously is what is incorrect, I doubt this has anything to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function upvote(id,bruger_id)
     {
         $.get("scripts/upvote.php?id="+id+"&bruger_id="+bruger_id, function() {
            $('.changeUp').attr('src', 'images/up.png');
            $('.changeUP').attr('onclick', 'noUpvote('.$feed[$loaded]["id"].','.$feed[$loaded]["bruger_id"].');');
         });
     }

    function noUpvote(id,bruger_id)
    {
         $.get("scripts/removevote.php?id="+id+"&bruger_id="+bruger_id, function() {
            $('.changeUP').attr('src', 'images/neutral_up.png');
            $('.changeUP').attr('onclick', 'upvote('.$feed[$loaded]["id"].','.$feed[$loaded]["bruger_id"].');');
         });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried your suggestion, seems like it changes it image back right away. Could it be possible to set some kind og session variable after the user presses the image and the checking the value of the session variable and chaning the image accordingly?

Comment: Do you want to have one function for both actions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your first method, `upvote()`, you are using a class selector with `changeUp` but you never change the class of the img tag with jQuery, then when you call the second method, with class selector `removeUp`, there is nothing with that class, try this:

```
function upvote(id, bruger_id)
{
  $.get("scripts/upvote.php?id="+id+"&bruger_id="+bruger_id, function() {
    $('.changeUp').attr('src', 'images/up.png');
    $('.changeUp').removeClass('changeUp').addClass('removeUp');
  }
}
```

Your img will be something like this:

```
<img class="removeUp" ...>
```

And you can call the second method and change the src attribute.

Greetings.

Comment: This worked if i add an attribute to the upvote function which changes  the .removeUp class the the neutral image. But this also has the downside that I cant press the image a third time.

Comment: You can do the same thing with the other method, but in reverse: `$('.removeUp').removeClass('removeUp').addClass('changeUp');`